# pentaho user console excel output

Tags: reporting-services, report, pentaho

I am trying to get excel report output from 'pentaho user console'. I created a cube in schema workbench and uploaded the cube and creating report out of it.

My excel report says "Unable to render report table. The table may not contain more than 10000 columns or more than 10000 rows."

My report has around 40000 rows. How can my excel report give me more than 10000 rows?

Can we change the row limit to a greater number?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Analyzer?  Thats the only place I can think where you would see this limit.  In which case you should take this up with Pentaho Support, as that means you must have an EE contract.

One thing to bear in mind though, OLAP tools e.g. analyzer/saiku/jpivot based on mondrian are not the place to be generating such large data exports anyway.  Possibly it should be reporting, or if very large perhaps just a transformation exposed via an xaction.  This is because there'll be a lot of effort in the reporting or analysis engine to export such a large amount of data - whereas in an ETL engine which is optimised for that it'll be much quicker.

Comment: I am using Analyzer Report. I am unable to see more than 10000 rows in Excel format.

Comment: I just exported in CSV which allowed me to download ~75k rows. Not in regular Excel format though

Comment: do you know the maximum size I can get as an Excel output?

Comment: Found that the default size of 10000 can be changed.

Comment: Great - Post the answer here then so you can help others!

Answer (score 1):

You have to change in the analyzer.properties in the Line 18

renderer.export.max.rows=10000 by the value that you want